# How do you choose between "о" and "ё" after sibilants for neologisms?

Tags: орфография

Let us imagine a poor student who considers that a voltage measuring device is called напряжометр (stressed О). Of course it's wrong; the correct word is вольтметр (voltmeter).

My question is: how do you write down this word if it is needed, e.g. to indicate a quote? For example, in an anecdote, where you must use it in the direct speech. Would it be **напряжометр** or **напряжёметр**? Russian is not immune to new words and occasionalisms. You know, there were writers and poets who invented new words (Velimir Khlebnikov, for instance).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My initial impulse was (and I luckily left it only as a comment) is to say that your particular choice of example is unfortunate - `ж` is never softened in modern Russian, while usage of ё implies palatalisation, so it would be напряжеметр. I don't know what have gotten into me, since this couldn't have been more wrong!

I immediately realised that, of course, in fact is exactly the opposite - according to rules, after `ж`,`ш`,`ч` and `щ` we write `ё` (if we have to choose between `ё`, `о` and `е`) or just `е` (if we are ignoring `ё`) if in related words in unstressed position it does not pronounced as `о`  - that's why `шёлковый`, `жёлтый` and `чёрный` but not жолтый, чорный or шолковый.

**So in your case it would be `напряжёметр`** (or just `напряжеметр`).

In the appendix below I've provided the exact set of rules. There's a very tricky note that states: "Иноязычные слова пишутся согласно произношению, например: крюшон, мажор, шомпол — шомпола, Чосер". Согласно произношению is an oversimplified way of saying "it's written this way just because it was adopted this way". But, again, in your case it's derivation from "напряжение".

Appendix: [Here's exact set](https://therules.ru/vowels-1/) of rules:

> Если после ж, ч, ш, щ произносится под ударением о, то буква о
> пишется: О правилах §§ 4—6:
>
> 1. В окончаниях имён существительных и прилагательных, например: плечо, ножом, шалашом, плечом, Фомичом, плащом, межой, вожжой, душой,
>    свечой, пращой, чужой, большой.
> 2. В суффиксах: а) имён существительных:
>    -ок, например: рожок, петушок, крючок, борщок;
>    -онок, например: медвежонок, мышонок, галчонок, бочонок;
>    -онк-а, например: книжонка, рубашонка, ручонка; также деньжонки; б) имён прилагательных:
>    -ов-, например: ежовый, грошовый, парчовый, холщовый;
>    -он (с беглым о), например: смешон; в) наречий, например: свежо, горячо, общо.
> 3. В именах существительных родительного падежа множественного числа на -ок, -он, например: кишок, княжон.
> 4. В словах (и в производных от них): обжора, крыжовник, жом, трещотка, трущоба, чащоба, чокаться, чопорный, Печора, шов, шорох,
>    шоры, в именах существительных: изжога, ожог, поджог (ср. написания с
>    -ёг в прошедшем времени глаголов: изжёг, ожёг, поджёг); также в некоторых областных и просторечных словах, например: жолкнуть, зажора
>    (и зажор), жох, ужо (в значении «потом», «после»), вечор (в значении
>    «вчера вечером»), чох (например, в выражении «не верит ни в сон, ни в
>    чох»), наречие чохом.
>
> *Во всех прочих случаях после ж, ч, ш, щ под ударением пишется буква ё, хотя и произносится о*

Comment: True, but. This case implies a comical effect, which is better conveyed with o... Кстати, они забыли слово "жопа" в п.4.

Answer (score 5):

I would write it as **напряжометр** since **-о-** is an interfix. Compare to [гальвано́метр](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80#%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0), [трапецо́эдр](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%BE%D1%8D%D0%B4%D1%80#%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0).

Don't quote me on this, but I believe interfixes should follow the same rules as endings and suffixes when it comes to о/ё.